# go install third part package, unrecognized import path

Tags: go, installation

Detail:

```
C:\>go get -u github.com/hidu/proxy-manager
package code.google.com/p/go.net/proxy: Get http://www.google.com/hangouts/: stopped after 10 redirects
package golang.org/x/crypto/blowfish: unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/crypto/blowfish"
package golang.org/x/crypto/cast5: unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/crypto/cast5"
package golang.org/x/crypto/salsa20/salsa: unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/crypto/salsa20/salsa"
```

I think maybe it because google is forbidden in china?
How to solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened a issue [here](https://github.com/hidu/proxy-manager/issues/2), solved by the help of repo owner.

The package I try to install is using `godep` and `go vendor`. 
`go vendor` need go 1.5 +, and the most important thing is :

```
export GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1
```

This command make install successful.

Comment: Nice feedback, more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is also because [code.google.com/p/go.net has been archived](http://code.google.com/p/go.net/proxy).

Make sure the project you are using includes a recent fork of that go.net project, like [`github.com/hashicorp/go.net`](https://github.com/hashicorp/go.net).

If you cannot change directly [github.com/hidu/proxy-manager](https://github.com/hidu/proxy-manager), you would need to fork it first.
Then change the import in [`hidu/proxy-manager/manager/client.go#L4`](https://github.com/hidu/proxy-manager/blob/3140de88c5bd5c23d5b95d4b87da5040c1d72026/manager/client.go#L4)

For the "unrecognized import path", [see this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/wPS4H5nkwyU):

> One common explanation is that something is blocking access to the `golang.org` domain.
>
> `go get -v golang.org/x/crypto/blowfish` should tell you more.

That last part works for me:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog>go get -v golang.org/x/crypto/blowfish
Fetching https://golang.org/x/crypto/blowfish?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/crypto/blowfish?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/crypto/blowfish": found meta tag 
    main.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/crypto", 
                    VCS:"git", 
                    RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/crypto"} 
at https://golang.org/x/crypto/blowfish?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/crypto/blowfish": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/crypto?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/crypto?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/crypto (download)
golang.org/x/crypto/blowfish
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is exactly the reason: You cannot `go get` from a repo which no longer _is_. (And you should not.)

Comment: I change the `client.go#L4` https://github.com/eromoe/proxy-manager/commit/20365284fc198438bc852f2495b1484ac50317c7 , and install by `go get -u github.com/eromoe/proxy-manager` but still same error. And `go get -v golang.org/x/crypto/blowfish` shows `https fetch failed`.

Comment: I find  `proxy-manager\Godeps\Godeps.json` also contain `code.google.com/p/go.net/proxy` . I change that ,but still not work. `$ go get -u github.com/eromoe/proxy-manager`
`package code.google.com/p/go.net/proxy: Get ``http://www.google.com/hangouts/: EOF`

Comment: @Mithril Maybe you need to solve the `https fetch failed` first. I have edited the answer to illustrate what that `go get -v golang.org/x/crypto/blowfish` should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Trying proxy

```bash
export GO111MODULE=on
export GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn
```